# Getting the volume of a sphere from an infinite product

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, volume, products

I read an article about squeezing pi from a menger sponge. You can see the original here: [Squeezing pi from a menger sponge](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/822984)

The author finds an infinite product which, he says, approximates the volume of a sphere with radius 1. The author mentions that the infinite product he found can be written in terms of the Wallis product. The equation given is:

$$8\prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(2n+1)^3-3(2n+1)+2}{(2n+1)^3}=\frac{4\pi}{3}$$

I do not know how to get the left hand side of the above equation in terms of the Wallis product. Hence, I do not know how to verify the equation. Please help.

For reference, the Wallis product is given by:

$$\prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2n}{2n-1}\cdot \frac{2n}{2n+1}=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You can derive this result as follows:

First, notice that:
$$(2n+1)^3-3(2n+1)+2 = 12n^2 + 8n^3 = 4n^2(2n+3)$$

Then, the product in your expression can be written as:
$$
\begin{align*}
\prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(2n+1)^3-3(2n+1)+2}{(2n+1)^3} &= \prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{4n^2(2n+3)}{(2n+1)(2n+1)(2n+1)} \overset{1}{=} \prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{4n^2(2n+3)}{(2n-1)(2n+1)(2n+1)} \\ &\overset{2}{=} \frac{1}{3}\prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{4n^2(2n+3)}{(2n-1)(2n+1)(2n+3)} = \frac{1}{3}\prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2n}{2n-1}\frac{2n}{2n+1} = \frac{\pi}{6}
\end{align*}
$$

In (1) I just included 2*1 - 1 = 1 in the product of the first term, effectively shifting the starting place once to the left. Similarly, in (2) I shifted the starting place of the product for the third term once to the right, putting the remaining 3 outside.

Multiplying this by 8 gives you the result you are looking for!

Comment: Thank you. Although I don't quite get the idea of "shifting the starting place". What is being done in steps 1 and 2? (Sorry... new to this)

Comment: It's ok! :) 

For (1) consider this:
$$\prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n+1)} = \frac{1}{3*5*7*...} = \frac{1}{1*3*5*7*...} = \prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n-1)}$$

while for (2):
$$\prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n+1)} = \frac{1}{3} \frac{1}{3*5*7*...} = \frac{1}{5*7*...} = \frac{1}{3} \prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n+3)}$$

In other words, for (1) I rewrote the general term of the product starting from 1 instead of 3 (multiplying by 1 does not change the result) while for (2) I left out the first term $\frac{1}{3}$ and rewrote the remaining product accordingly.